# What is the meaning of the phrase "What it is to be"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase "What it is to be"? in sentences like "What it is to be a man?" or "what it is to be a leader?" or in a sentence like this:

> It might have been hoped, Up until the middle of the 19th century or so, that we could account for the world completely in terms of the motions of sort of Newtonian material particles. Towards the end of the century, with the development of Maxwellian electromagnetism, it became clear that, that wasn't the case. And that the fundamental architecture of the world includes at least one other thing, namely fields. The big thing that's happened in physics, since the end of the 19th century, that affects these debates a great deal is quantum mechanics. And there is a debate going on now, about what the appropriate sort of ontology of quantum mechanics is, what we ought to read quantum mechanics is telling us fundamentally exist. So at the moment, we are hoping we can get along with an ontology of particles and fields. But of course, science develops and changes and is full of surprises. And we'll have to see. Other old questions are whether there are altogether different kinds of entities in the world. Entities like God, mind, or The good. And I think that the physical project has been committed from the beginning to, at least, seeing what extent to which we can get along with just recognizably physical fundamental entities, like particles and fields. But exactly **what it is to be** a fundamental physical entity, is itself an open question.

> [Source: closer to truth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovvnt3FuhBo)

Comment: You need an antecedent and I am not going watch YouTube to find it. Cheers.

Comment: I'm not gonna follow the specific link either, but I watch that Youtube channel myself, so I can pretty confidently assert that *What it is to be a man* equates to the answer to the question ***What does "being a man" mean**?* (in some other contexts, those same words might mean *What is it **like** to be a man?,* but that's slightly different).

Comment: @Lambie I edit it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I edit it. Can you look at it now and tell if this makes a difference to your previous answer. thanks.

Comment: This is really about philosophy, not "learning English". The final sentence of your cited text simply means ***We don't know** what it "means" to be "a fundamental physical entity"*. Knowing that particular Youtube channel, I'd say they could just as well have said we don't even know ***if there is such a thing*** as "a fundamental physical entity" (perhaps there is no such thing as "physical reality" within which "separate things" could even exist at all). But the basic syntactic construction here is the same as *Because I'm a man, I can't really know **what it is** to be a woman.*